# Is there any way to insert data in parent and child model in one graphql mutation

Tags: python, graphql, hasura

I have a model named `Project` and a `CustomProject` model that inherits from it. Currently, I have two mutations one to add a project and one to add a custom project

```
class Project(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()

class CustomProject(Project): 
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)

mutation InsertProjects(
  $projects: [graph_project_insert_input!]! = [
    {
      url: "https://github.com/smsajjadzaidi/FixedRouteSuggestion"
      description: "_test_desc_"
    }
  ]
) {
  projects: insert_graph_project(
    objects: $projects
    on_conflict: {
      constraint: graph_project_pkey
      update_columns: [url, description]
    }
  ) {
    returning {
      id
    }
    affected_rows
  }
}


mutation InsertCustomProject(
  $projects: [custom_project_insert_input!]! = [
    {
      project_ptr_id: 2
      role:"author"
    }
  ]
) {
  customprojects: insert_custom_project(
    objects: $projects
    on_conflict: {
      constraint: custom_project_pkey
      update_columns: [role]
    }
  ) {
    returning {
      graph_project{
        id
      }
    }
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

Need a way to do the above in one mutation

Comment: Hi friend, there is an entry in Hasura docs for this https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/mutations/insert/#pg-nested-inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mutation InsertCustomProject(
  $url: String = "_____test______"
  $description: String = "___test____"
  $role: String = "author"
  
  $title: String = "__test__"
) {
  repositories: insert_customproject_one(
    object: {
      role: $role
      project: {
        data: {
          url: $url
          description: $description
          
        }
        on_conflict: {
          constraint: project_pkey
          update_columns: [url, description]
        }
      }
    }
    on_conflict: {
      constraint: customproject_pkey
      update_columns: [role]
    }
  ) {
    project_id: project_ptr_id
  }
}
```